# Obter valor seleciona form_dropdown

Tags: php, javascript

Olá, tenho o seguinte trecho de codigo

```
onkeypress="mascaraMutuario(this,cnpj)
```

Onde trata-se de uma que cria uma mascara para CNPJ ou CPF. Porém, tenho

```
<?php
    $bs = array('0' => '', '1' => 'Pessoa Física', '2' => 'Pessoa Jurídica');
    echo form_dropdown('tipo', $bs, set_value('tipo', '0'), 'class="form-control select2" id="tipo" required="required" style="width:100%;"');
?>
```

Onde eu gostaria que ao depender do tipo de pessoa selecionada ele chamasse a minha função especifica, passando por parametro o CNPJ ou CPF.

Comment: Sua pergunta não esta muito clara, mas pelo o que eu entendi, você quer modificar uma área da página de acordo com a seleção de pessoa física ou jurídica, é isso?

Comment: é exatamente isso

Comment: Você deve fazer isso usando javascript.

Comment: Teria algum exemplo de como posso fazer?

Comment: Mas o que você quer fazer na tela?

Comment: que colocar a mascara, dependendo do tipo de pessoa selecionada, em um inpput

Comment: vou fazer aqui como sua resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz a resposta como conversado nos comentários, todo o código esta comentado para melhor entendimento.

```js
$(function() {
  
  // Copio os campos
  var cpf = $("#input-group-cpf").clone();
  var cnpj = $("#input-group-cnpj").clone();
  
  // Removo os campos da tela
  $("#input-group-cpf").remove();
  $("#input-group-cnpj").remove();
  
  // Adiciono como padrao o cpf
  $(".numero-documento").append(cpf);
  
  atualizaMascara();
  
  //Coloco o evento clique no radio
  $('[name="pessoa"]').on("click", function(){
  
   // Removo os campos da tela
    $("#input-group-cpf").remove();
    $("#input-group-cnpj").remove();
   
    // E adiciona o campo correspondente de acordo com o valor do radio
    if($(this).val() == "fisica"){
     $(".numero-documento").append(cpf);
    }else{
     $(".numero-documento").append(cnpj);
    }
    
    atualizaMascara();
    
  });
  
});

function atualizaMascara(){
 $(".numero-documento").find("#input-group-cpf").find("input").mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
  $(".numero-documento").find("#input-group-cnpj").find("input").mask('00.000.000/0000-00', {reverse: true});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="pessoa" value="fisica" checked> Pessoa Física<br>
<input type="radio" name="pessoa" value="juridica"> Pessoa Jurídica<br>

<div class="numero-documento">
  <div id="input-group-cpf">
    <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
    <input type="text" class="cpf" id="cpf"/>
  </div>

  <div id="input-group-cnpj">
    <label for="cnpj">CNPJ</label>
    <input type="text" class="cnpj" id="cnpj"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito bom....obrigado.

Comment: Por favor, avalie a resposta positivamente e marque como a sua resposta ;)